# how to set a class level variable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to set a variable in a VBA class module, that will increment up every time an instance of the class is initialized.

For example, the 1st instance of the class would have a number of "1",  the next would be "2",  etc.

I apologize if my terminology is not correct.

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
     Number=Number+1<-- This variable would increment every time there is a new instance
End Sub
```

Comment: Whats your reason for getting the count of instances?

Comment: This code should be correct. Just make sure that `Number` is actually a class variable. In other words, it has to be static.

Answer (score 3):

Declare a global or public variable  `Public NumberOfInstances as Long` in a Module.

Then use this code in the class:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    NumberOfInstances = NumberOfInstances + 1
End Sub
```

If you want to know which number each instance has, you need to add a member variable to the class and also initialise it, e.g.:

```
Private mInstanceCount as Long

Public Property Get InstanceCount() as Long: InstanceCount = mInstanceCount: End Property

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    NumberOfInstances = NumberOfInstances + 1
    mInstanceCount = NumberOfInstances
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable at the top of the class - Static Number

You can't declare a static class varaible in VBA !
It would be possible with a true OO language such as Java.

Comment: VBA doesn't allow to declare static variables inside class modules.